# Template to get map element with default value

Tags: c++, dictionary

**The problem:**

I'm trying to make a function `getmap` that gets a `map<string, string>` element, but if none exists return a specified default value (i.e. `getmap(mymap, "keyA", mydefault);`.

I templated it for `int, float` and `char*` return types but I get an error:

```
error C2664: 'getmap' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'const char *' to 'char *const '
```

even though I'm not using `char *const`. Why is this happening?

**The code:**

```
template <typename T> inline
T getmap(const std::map<std::string, std::string> &m, const char* key, const T def, T (*f)(const char*) = NULL) {
    std::map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator i = m.find(std::string(key));
    return i == m.end() ? def : (f == NULL ? i->second.c_str() : f(i->second.c_str()));
}

inline int getmap(const std::map<std::string, std::string> &m, const char* key, const int def) {
    return getmap<int>(m, key, def, &std::atoi);
}

float atofl(const char* s) {
    return (float)std::atof(s);
}

inline float getmap(const std::map<std::string, std::string> &m, const char* key, const float def) {
    return getmap<float>(m, key, def, &atofl);
}

inline char* getmap(const std::map<std::string, std::string> &m, const char* key, const char* def) {
    return getmap<char*>(m, key, def);  // ERROR HERE
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to pass in a const char* to a function that expects a pointer to a function?

Comment: why are you using `char*` at all?

Comment: @user814628 - where are you referring to? Thanks

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich - the map is `<string, string>`, but I just want to be able to do something like `getmap(mymap, "keyA", mydefault);` without having to do `std::string("keyA")` first.

Comment: @MiloChen Nevermind, ready it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getmap<char*>(m, key, def);`

makes the `T` of `getmap` a `char*`. The 3rd argument you accept is a `const T`. I know that looks like that should make it a `const char*` but that actually makes it a `char* const`.

You are then trying to pass a `const char*` to a `char* const`, as the error says. You can pass a non-const to a const, but not the other way around.

So write this instead...

```
getmap<const char*>(m, key, def);
       ^^^^^
```

Comment: Just make parameter and T of type `const char*const` ?